# Select Join for two columns in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello everybody;

```
Table 1
    id product_name location added_by updated_by added date
    1  LENOVO       St 23    2        1          2016-08-26

Table 2
id first_name last_name email
1  John       Doe       jd@email.com
2  Peter      Smith     ps@email.com
```

I would like to know how to select data with codeigniter query in order to get result like this

```
product_name location added_by    updated_by
LENOVO       St 23    Peter Smith John Doe
```

I have tried with join but `added_by` column and `updated_by` column display same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used this query for your problem :

```
$this->db->select('t1.product_name,t1.location, CONCAT(t2_1.first_name, " ", t2_1.last_name) AS added_by, CONCAT(t2_2.first_name, " ", t2_2.last_name) AS updated_by'); 
$this->db->from('Table 1 t1');
$this->db->join('Table 2 t2_1', 't2_1.id = t1.added_by', 'left'); 
$this->db->join('Table 2 t2_2', 't2_2.id = t1.updated_by', 'left'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

you can changes according your table name inside query **Table 1** and **Table 2**

Comment: Thank you @Nikunj Rathod for your answers; solved my problem;

Comment: please approve this answer for it can be helpfull for others member.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$this->db->select('*')
  ->from('Table 1')
  ->join('Table 2', 'Table 2.id = Table 1.added_by', 'left')
  ->join('Table 2', 'Table 2.id = Table 1.updated_by', 'left');

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you but I got this error: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1066

Table/alias: Table 2' non unique

Comment: `->join('Table 2 as t22', 't22.id = Table 1.added_by', 'left')`
`->join('Table 2 as t23', 't23.id = Table 1.updated_by', 'left');`
change the join fields like this and see what happens

Comment: Thank you @Sayantan Das for your answers; answer for user Nikunj Rathod solved my problem;

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this query for joining with multiple column**

```
$this->db->select('*')
->from('table_1')

->join('table_2', 'table_2.id = table_1.added_by AND table_2.id = table_1.updated_by', 'left');

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```